# Is $\frac{1}{x(1+x)}$ a well-defined generating function?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, generating-functions, formal-power-series

Is this a well-defined generating function? $$\frac{1}{x(1+x)}$$

We know that  $\:\frac{1}{(1+x)} = \sum_{n \ge0}(-1)^nx^n$,$\:$ hence the notation $\frac{1}{x}\sum_{n \ge0}(-1)^nx^n \:$ would act as a shift for the coefficients $f(n) = (-1)^n$ to the prior power of $x$, however $\:\frac{1}{(1+x)}$ has the constant term.

I found it in an example and probably I must have misinterpreted something

Comment: It is not a generating function $\sum a_ix^i$ of a sequence $(a_i)$ of real numbers, because a generating function always has a finite value at $x=0$.

Comment: Sure, if $f(n)=(-1)^{n+1}$ For $n\geq -1.$ But normally we define generating functions for functions defined for $n\geq 0.$ The normal shift operation would give $$\frac{1}{x(x+1)}-\frac1x=-\frac1{1+x}.$$ It his hard to guess where your error was if you were evaluating a normal generating function.

Comment: Typo. “ … It **is** hard to say…”

Comment: There are many variations on generating functions. The most common is ordinary generating function for sequences $\,a_0,a_1,\dots\,$ For sequences that have terms with negative index, the corresponding Laurent series is the appropriate generating function. For example, the [$j$-invariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J-invariant) has the Laurent series expansion $1/q+744+196884q+\dots$ whose coefficients are [OEIS sequence A000521](https://oeis.org/A000521).

Comment: @Somos thank you for clarifying